# Cut zero chars (string[:-0]) from string - Python

Tags: python, string, python-2.7

Why does `[:-0]` return an empty string? There is a variable in my code which determines a length of string which have to be cut. The problem is that it returns empty string when there is int(0) in this variable.

Example:

```
def rightPass(word,value):
    substring = word[:-value]
    return substring

for i in range(3,-1,-1):
    print rightPass('word',i)

>>> w
>>> wo
>>> wor
>>>
```

I do know that it is not a big deal to do this:

```
def rightPass(word,value):
    substring = word[:-value] if value!=0 else word
    return substring
```

But I can't find a reason why is `[:-0]` acting this way.

I though that it is because Python doesn't know `-0` value but I tried it using `0` and the same problem occurred.

Can somebody explain it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are asking Python to create a new string from index 0 to index 0. And that's an empty slice.

The *end value* of a slice is exclusive. Python picks all characters from the starting index that come *before* the end index. Here `-0` is the same thing as `0` (negative zero is the same thing as positive zero).

Note that that is different from using actual negative values; `[0:-1]` would take the length and replace the negative value with `len(object) - 1` and use that as the end value, but this *doesn't work for `-0`*, because that is not a negative value!

You can use `None` instead of `0` if you wanted to slice to the end:

```
substring = word[:-value if value else None]
```

Comment: Thank you, of course I meant range(3,-1,-1). I've edited my question.

Answer (score 1):

The second parameter in the slice is the end position.

```
[start : stop : step]
```

And the range of `start` to `stop` is half open, meaning it includes `start` **up to but not including** `stop`.

So `[: 0]` means start at `[0]` and stop at but don't include `[0]`, which can only be empty string.